# Javascript Parent/ Child Id Control

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can the name of a window opened using window.open be changed dynamically by the main parent?

We have a menu system that opens new windows when a link is clicked. The new window then has other windows that can be opened from it. This method works fine in a one session environment. But when users try to open a second window from the same option the first window is replaced. I know this is due to them both using the same name. Can the main menu program be coded to change the name each time a menu item is clicked? Can this same menu program change the name of the children windows from the first window?

The best method I can think of is finding a way for a javascript listener to be opened and triggers each time a link is clicked, within each separate parent/child tree. I however don't even know if this is possible.

I know I have the option to append a unique number to each window.open command name, but I am looking for a way to allow the menu program to handle this.

I am looking for a method that won't require changing the child programs.

Thank you.

Comment: What about passing a message to the child window and having it change the title attribute?

Comment: just change `window.name` property within the child window, or the  name property on the window reference object you get from window.open, ie `var w = window.open(); w.name="something";`

Comment: I would need to set up a method in the each program that will be a called to receive and handle the message? @zero298

Comment: @PatrickEvans This method will work for the first window called but then each window called from that one won't be unique. If they open two vendor links those vendor links will spawn child with the same name unless I change the vendor program as well.

Comment: use a `uuid` to have universal unique identiifer so no nameing cnflict exists. exa,ple uuid: `var cnt=0; function uuid(NS){ return [NS||"namespace", new Date().getTime(), ++cnt].join('_');}`